# Getting case fan speed from GPU temperature

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, fan-controller

In my current setup, the case fans are controlled using the CPU temperature, however, this is not the correct metric since GPU is generally hotter and is used more. I know that it is not possible to set up this relation in bios, but I can think of three options:

1. Connect a splitter to the GPU fan assembly and connect the case fans along with the GPU fans to it (I think my GPU uses a simple 3-pin connector). The issue that I have with this setup is that it may cause additional strain on the GPU's power delivery and will not look quite as appealing.
2. The same as 1, but only get the speed reeding from the GPU. I have no idea how to do this, but maybe someone does and the jank factor is not removed here either.
3. Buy an Arduino and a temperature sensor and write some code to control fans with it. This seems perfect, but a little hard to accomplish.

The reason that I want to do these specific things is that I am looking for a hardware option, which is as cheap as possible and does not require much space (like a 3.5 slot in the pc case). I wonder if I'm missing something? I know that there are small fan controllers which have a temperature sensor, but there you can't control the speed curve, which I would definitely like to do. Anyway, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Great question! I'm worried it's a bit off-topic for this community though. I would personally take the Arduino approach, since you can connect the Arduino to USB and write software to control the Arduino over COM and take advantage of all of the PC-side data and the Arduino inputs. There is an Arduino stack exchange community that will be very helpful in accomplishing this.

Comment: "Argus Monitor" is apparently a suitable software solution:
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-to-set-fan-curve-based-on-gpu-temperature.3577241/post-22107164